# Issue building a crosstab requery on Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, crosstab

I am having an issue working on an Access application, I would like to fill a Listview using a Xtab requery. The requery would take one of the column field values and create Y columns if there are Y different values for that field.

The tab is looking like that :

Assoc_tasks_cat(***ID*** (prim key), fk_taskID, fk_category, nbHours)

I would like the requery to group all rows with same *fk_taskID* values and fill Category columns with associated *nbHours* values.

I thought it would be netter with a small schema :

-[The initial tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMBKU.png)

-[The wanted view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwXC0.png)

In addition, I specify you that there are no duplicated value of *fk_category* for one value of *fk_taskID*. As example :

(**1** (prim key), 1, "Cat1", 5);
(**2** (prim key), 1, "Cat1", 7); rows are **NOT** possible

Does anyone know how the SQL requery should look like ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution by myself

I just had to use the GROUP BY keyword in conjonction with PIVOT keyword

so the final request looks like this :

```
TRANSFORM sum(nbHours) AS SumNbHours
SELECT fk_taskID
FROM TabName
GROUP BY fk_taskID
PIVOT fk_category
```

Easier than I thought :)